# how to have a Shared Transaction between Oracle ADF ApplicationModule and JPA in a @Transactional Method of a Spring Service?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, oracle-adf

I would like to call a method of an **Oracle ADF** `ApplicationModule` from a `@Transactional` method of a Spring `Service` where I call JPA `EntityManager` methods as well. These calls need to be committed in the same transaction. Both use the same `DataSource` and my Application Server is **Weblogic 10.3.5**. How can I Achieve this?

When I use `JtaTransactionManager`, my Application Module changes are committed but, changes by `JPA` are **not**. And when I use `JpaTransactionManager`, `ApplicationModule` changes are not committed.

This is my Spring Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee         
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="testspring.view"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/hrDS"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="testspring.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

This is my Service class:

```
package testspring.view;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import oracle.jbo.client.Configuration;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import testspring.adfmodel.AppModuleImpl;

import testspring.model.Regions;


@Service
public class HelloBS {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public HelloBS() {
        super();
    }

    @Transactional()
    public void doSomething() {
        AppModuleImpl am = null;
        String amDef = "testspring.adfmodel.AppModule";
        String config = "AppModuleLocal";

        am = (AppModuleImpl)Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(amDef, config);
        am.insertRegions("ADF");

        Regions region = new Regions();
        region.setRegionName("JPA");
        entityManager.persist(region);
    }
}
```

Something I would like to add is that I tried the same scenario using `EJB` Beans and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simplified my question and removed the ADF part and posted it as another question here:
[Why are JPA changes using an EntityManager not committed in a Spring Service when JtaTransactionManager is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498250/why-are-jpa-changes-using-an-entitymanager-not-committed-in-a-spring-service-whe/37509827#37509827)

After getting some help from **@Bond - Java Bond** and some more research I found the answer and posted it at that question. That answer applies to this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is sharing the same java.sql.Connection between both environments.

I don't think you can pass a connection to ADF BC, as AMs are managing their connections transparently, but you can use the connection created by ADF BC and pass it to Spring.
But I am not sure that spring can work like this- you have to check with people with more recent Spring experience than I do.

What you can do is use ADF BC and JDBC in the same transaction, for sure.

Comment: Actually I use declarative and annotation based transaction management. So, I can't pass connection to my JPA EntityManager. As I mentioned it worked with EJB and there should be a way in Spring as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you overwrite the commit of your JPA part to first commit the ADF part and only if it works commit the JPA part?

I don't think you can use a single transaction manager for both. The only exception might be if you are exposing your AM as a web service and managing the transactions of calls to that web service externally.

Comment: I believe there should be a way using a special kind of `TransactionManager`. So, I prefer not to program it manually. Another solution that I'm going to try and may help me is to expose `ApplicationModule` as an `EJB` and use it in Spring Service. Thanks for your comment anyway.