# Why are JPA changes using an EntityManager not committed in a Spring Service when JtaTransactionManager is used?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to use `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` as my `TransactionManager` in Spring `Service`. However, it does not commit any change in JPA entities. I know that if I use `JpaTransactionManager` it works. But, I need `JtaTransactionManager`. So, please don't recommend to use `JpaTransactionManager`.
My Spring `Service` class is:

```
package testspring.view;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import testspring.model.Regions;


@Service
public class HelloBS {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public HelloBS() {
        super();
    }

    @Transactional()
    public void doSomething() {
        Regions region = new Regions();
        region.setRegionName("Antarctica");
        entityManager.persist(region);
    }
}
```

And my Spring xml config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee         
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="testspring.view"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/hrDS"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="testspring.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

How can I have changes in JPA entities committed using `JtaTransactionManager`?

Comment: Do try following two things - (1) In `entityManagerFactory` bean set `jtaDataSource` instead of `dataSource` (2) Replace `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` with `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>`

Comment: The second suggestion had no effect and by applying the first one I got this error: `org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate` Thanks for your comment Mr. Bond :)

Comment: THANK YOU BOND I LOVE YOU PLEASE MERRY ME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **@Bond - Java Bond** the solution is to do the following steps:

- Set `jtaDataSource` instead of `dataSource`.
- Use `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>` instead of `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`.
- Add `<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>`. There are different classes in `org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal` package that can be used for different Application Servers.

So the final Spring xml config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

       xsi:schemaLocation="        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee         
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="testspring.view"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/hrDS"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="testspring.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>        
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>

</beans>
```